# Check if the string has $any_thing_between_dollarSigns$ or @any_thing_between'@'Sign@ how to do it in asp.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, oop

I have a text box. Text box values are:

> My Name is $John$ The $Developer$

What I want to do? I want to pick and store only those words which are between `$___$` signs.

I tried by using `value.Contain("")` but I have to write the complete word.

Comment: does this only apply to words or do you also want something like  `$any$way` to match `"any"` ?

Comment: I want to pick those words which are between Dollar Signs like $any$ is your test word $Libra$ gathers due cause $value$

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with regular expressions:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string sentence = "My Name is $John$ The $Developer$"; //or TextBox1.Text;
//split sentence into words and store them in a collection
var allWords = Regex.Split(sentence, @"\s+").Where(s => s != string.Empty);
//collection to store $words$
var wordsInDollarSigns = new List<string>();

//loop through all words in allWords
foreach(string word in allWords)
{
    //if a word matches your requirement, add it in wordsInDollarSigns
    if (Regex.IsMatch(word, @"\$(.+?)\$"))
    {
        wordsInDollarSigns.Add(word);
        //to remove $ from the words use the following instead
        wordsInDollarSigns.Add(word.Replace("$", string.Empty));
    }
}

//wordsInDollarSigns now contains the matches
```

**Update**: Per your new requirement of not storing the `"$"` character in your matched words collection, see the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`value.Split('$')`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Every second entry in the result array will be a substring between '$'.

Comment: but how am i going to pick those values, after splitting?

Comment: @John Just loop over the items and ignore the first, third, fifth etc. item?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
'' Textbox Values in the Variable
valuefromTextbox = txtString.Text.ToString()

''Split the value and by Space and save it into Array.
Dim arrayofvaluefromTextboxSplitted As String() = valuefromTextbox.Split(" ")
'' Now I want to get those words from a string which are surrounded by $Anyword$...
For Each word As String In arrayofvaluefromTextboxSplitted

Dim arrayforSplittedSecondIndex As String() = Nothing
    '' Store the word which is surrounded by $ sign
    If Regex.IsMatch(word, "\$(.+?)\$") Then
        '' This will split by $ sign and will take the 2nd(which is 1) index value of arrayselect. I want word without $$ sign
        arrayforSplittedSecondIndex = word.Split("$")
        word = arrayforSplittedSecondIndex(1).ToString()
        '' Store the value in a variable
        selectValueInlbl = word.Trim.ToString()
        lblcheckSelect.Text += word & "<br/>"
        arrayforSplittedSecondIndex = Nothing
    End If
Next
```